# how to avoid deeply nested callbacks in call FireStore (Firebase)'s api by kotlin coroutine

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, kotlin-coroutines

How can I prevent having deeply nested callbacks when using the Firebase/Firestore API?

Py app call firestore api step by step, and i need do something process when `onSuccess` and `onFailed`.

For example, it need 5 steps. For going to the next step, it needs reference to pre-call api's result.

1st Step : `getA() // get A Data from firestore`

2nd Step : `if(resultGetA.isSuccess) getB() else updateC()`

3rd Step : `if(resultGetB.isSuccess) addD()`

4th Step : `if(resultAddD.isSuccess) updateE()`

5th Step : `if(resultUpdateE.isSuccess) getF()`

example to kotlin code

This is just an example source for explain my question,
but my application's code similar like this :(

```kotlin
fun callHellExample1(email:String, pass:String, model:UserDataModel) {
        val collectRef = Firebase.firestore.collection("A")
        val auth = Firebase.auth

        auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass).addOnCompleteListener { createTask ->
            if (createTask.isSuccessful) {
                auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass).addOnCompleteListener { signInTask ->
                    if (signInTask.isSuccessful) {
                        collectRef.add(model).addOnCompleteListener {
                            Toast.makeText(this, "complete create account", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                        }
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(this, "failed create account in Step 2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    }
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "failed create account in Step 1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
    }


fun callHellExample2(callback : (Boolean)-> Unit) {
        val collectRef = Firebase.firestore.collection("A")
        val auth = Firebase.auth

        collectRef.document("A").get().addOnCompleteListener { resultA ->
            if(resultA.isSuccessful){
                collectRef.document("B").get().addOnCompleteListener { resultB ->
                    if(resultB.isSuccessful){
                        collectRef.add("D").addOnCompleteListener { resultD ->
                            if(resultD.isSuccessful){
                                collectRef.document("E").update("someFiled", "someValue").addOnCompleteListener { resultE ->
                                    if(resultE.isSuccessful){
                                        collectRef.document("F").get().addOnCompleteListener {
                                            auth.signOut()
                                            callback(true)
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(this, "getB ... isSuccessful? = ${resultB.isSuccessful}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    }
                }
            }else{
                collectRef.document("C").update("someFiled", "someValue").addOnCompleteListener { resultC ->
                    Toast.makeText(this, "update C ... isSuccessful? = ${resultC.isSuccessful}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

so i try use by coroutine. but i can't found escape callback hell about firestore api

i tried like this (example 1). but it similar like callback hell.
i want check it successful.

await() return not `Task<AuthResult>`. it just return `AuthResult`
but `AuthResult` is not contains `isSuccessful` variable

```kotlin
fun example1ByCoroutine(email:String, pass:String, mode:UserModel){
        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
            try{
                auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass).await()
                try{
                    auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass).await()
                    try{
                        collectRef.add(model).await()
                        withContext(Dispatchers.Main){
                            Toast.makeText(this, "complete create account", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                        }
                    }catch (e: Exception){
                        Toast.makeText(this, "failed create account in Step 3", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    }
                }catch (e: Exception){
                    Toast.makeText(this, "failed create account in Step 2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            }catch (e: Exception){
                Toast.makeText(this, "failed create account in Step 1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
    }
```

example 2 is can not show toast cuz can not check isSuccessful too.
is not return Task. it just return DocumentSnapShot

i look forward to your reply.
thanks!

ps) if can access to isSuccessful, code can be edit like this

```
fun example1ByCoroutine(email:String, pass:String, mode:UserModel){
        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
            if(!auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass).await().isSuccessful){
                Toast.makeText(this, "failed create account in Step 1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                return@launch
            }

            if(!auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass).await().isSuccessful){
                Toast.makeText(this, "failed create account in Step 2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                return@launch
            }
            
            if(collectRef.add(model).await().isSuccessful){
                Toast.makeText(this, "failed create account in Step 3", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                return@launch
            }
                    
            withContext(Dispatchers.Main){
                Toast.makeText(this, "complete create account", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would not advice to re-implement the `Task.await()` method to return the task itself again, instead you can add a simple wrapper to the standard kotlin `Result` class:

```
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task
import kotlinx.coroutines.tasks.await

suspend fun <T> Task<T>.awaitResult() = runCatching { await() }
```

And then use it like this:

```
suspend fun foo(email: String, pass: String){
    if(auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass).awaitResult().isFailure){
        Toast.makeText(this, "failed create account in Step 1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        return
    }

    if(auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass).awaitResult().isFailure){
        Toast.makeText(this, "failed create account in Step 2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        return
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Coroutines have integration with Google Play Services [Tasks API](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/tasks).

Just add this dependency:

```
implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-play-services:1.4.1'
```

You can convert a Task into a Deferred using `Task.asDeferred`.
Similarly, `Task.await` Awaits for completion of the Task (cancellable).

You can read more about it here : https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/tree/master/integration/kotlinx-coroutines-play-services